# should we use StackPanel or Grid as Listbox item template

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, grid, datatemplate, stackpanel

I heard that in order to improve `Listbox` performance, we should use simple `ListBoxItem` template.

In every `Listbox` row, I want to display 3 images. Should I use horizontal `StackPanel` for those 3 images, or `Grid` with 3 columns ?

And, should I specify the height of `StackPanel`/`Grid` ? Doing this gains better performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While making a Listbox, the best practice is to use a StackPanel. 
The basic difference between a StackPanel and Grid is that, the StackPanel will automatically adjust the Orientation of each ItemTemplate as and when it is added.

If you decide to use a StackPanel, you do not need to specify the Width. You could However specify the Maximum Height of the Stack Panel to make your ListBox look better.

There is no harm in using a Grid either. It would perhaps be a better idea to use a Grid if you wish to have columns of Alpha-Numeric Data.

Comment: thanks, but which is best for Listbox item template, in term of performance ?

Comment: if I use StackPanel, I just specify its Height ? Because I heard that Listbox item template must be of fixed height to make scrolling smooth ?

Comment: Yes, By specifying the Height, the scrolling does get better. You can also set the MaxHeight and the MinHeight properties to enhance the Listbox scrolling even better

Comment: When I said smooth scrolling, I mean VirtualizingStackPanel. Is Height not enough ?